# How can i find if an <a> has a specific class when it is in an <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have the follow html:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <a class="myListItem li-selected">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="myListItem">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="myListItem li-selected">Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="myListItem">Four</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="myListItem">Five</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The **li-selected** class is added when the respective <li> tag is getting selected.
I am trying in **$(document).ready()** to check if any of the li's is selected (having **li-selected** class).
As a result I am expecting a boolean to use every time the page loads to pass it in an other function as a parameter.

I am trying something like this but it doesn't return **true** although it should:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        .
        .
        .
   var hasSelectedItems = $("#myList li").find("a").hasClass("li-selected");
   console.log(hasSelectedItems);
        .
        .
        .
});
```

Expected result:

- **hasSelectedItems** === **true** then at least one <li> is selected.
- **hasSelectedItems** === **false** then no <li> is selected.

***SOLVED***

As it turned out there was nothing wrong with the way I was trying to check if the **li-selected** class existed but with the when I was trying to do it. I misplaced the `var hasSelectedItems = $("#myList li").find("a").hasClass("li-selected");` part and tried to find a class that hadn't been added yet. So I moved that part of the code to run when the elements are rerendered after the addition of the **li-selected** class and it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pe4jn6e9/1/ - looks fine - `lis` is `true`

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work in my code... If i fix it I will post the results

Comment: @MavrosGatos If you can recreate the issue using the above fiddle we can try to help you else there is not much that we can do

Comment: @MavrosGatos Define 'not working'. Does it give you an error or nothing? Are you logging the results?

Comment: The problem was that although I was placing my code at the end of $(document).ready my html hadn't been drawn yet. So I moved my code just after the part of my code that I .add the ".li-selected" and it works great. Thnks everybody..

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following jquery code to find `a` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lis = $("#myList li a.li-selected").length;
    if(lis > 0)
    {
     //code here
    }
    else
    {
     //empty
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can rather find the length of anchor elements that have class li selected:

```
var lis = $("#myList li a.li-selected").length > 0 ;
```